# Error in R: magick_image_annotate() on macOS NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4405

Tags: r, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm new to macOS, and I can't get the image_annotate() function to work in the magick package in R.

Code:

```
img = image_read("--- any png path ---")
image_annotate(img,"test")
```

Error:

```
Error in magick_image_annotate(image, text, gravity, location, degrees,  : 
  rsession-arm64: NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4405
```

My magick configuration:

```
require(magick)
Loading required package: magick
Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript, x11

magick_config()
$version
[1] ‘6.9.12.3’

$modules
[1] FALSE

$cairo
[1] TRUE

$fontconfig
[1] TRUE

$freetype
[1] TRUE

$fftw
[1] FALSE

$ghostscript
[1] FALSE

$heic
[1] TRUE

$jpeg
[1] TRUE

$lcms
[1] TRUE

$libopenjp2
[1] TRUE

$lzma
[1] TRUE

$pangocairo
[1] TRUE

$pango
[1] TRUE

$png
[1] TRUE

$raw
[1] TRUE

$rsvg
[1] TRUE

$tiff
[1] TRUE

$webp
[1] TRUE

$wmf
[1] FALSE

$x11
[1] FALSE

$xml
[1] TRUE

$`zero-configuration`
[1] TRUE

$threads
[1] 1
```

I guess Ghostscript should be enabled (it is under windows), is there a way to just enable it?

I tried some more brew installations like

```
brew install gs
brew install fontconfig
brew install librsvg
```

and a lot more reinstallations of magick packages. Everything seems fine, but image_annotate() still produce this error.

Comment: [The Ultimate Guide to Installing Ghostscript](https://blog.finxter.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-installing-ghostscript/#:~:text=Checking%20for%20Ghostscript%20on%20Mac,then%20Ghostscript%20is%20not%20installed.) has a section "Checking if Ghostscript is Already Installed" which has a macOS subsection.

Comment: You should only need `ghostscript` if reading PDF files, otherwise not. I think you are missing a parameter, as `-annotate` usually requires an angle as its parameter (on the command line at least). Try checking the parameters in your docs - wherever they are. Maybe `annotate(img, angle=0, "text")`

Comment: Thanks for response, but this is set default to 0 (guess its called degree here) in R. Same code just works on windows.

R docs:
image_annotate(
  image,
  text,
  gravity = "northwest",
  location = "+0+0",
  degrees = 0,
  size = 10,
  font = "",
  style = "normal",
  weight = 400,
  kerning = 0,
  decoration = NULL,
  color = NULL,
  strokecolor = NULL,
  boxcolor = NULL
)

Comment: I note neither JPEG nor PNG appear in your *"Enabled features"* line? Maybe try finding a WEBP image on the net (as that is apparently enabled) and see if you can write on that.